# How to aggregate similar test failures in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

How to aggregate similar test failures in Jenkins?

We use Jenkins and every once in a while we'll get hundreds (700+ at the moment) of failures when testing against Oracle.  Most of them are a generic failure during startup failures, finding the ones that aren't is challenging to do manually (700+) links to click on.  We'd like some way for the same type failures to be aggregated so we can easily see the ones that aren't all the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use some kind of XSD to transform the current XML into one that aggregates the same errors and maybe puts a count in there so it will say something like error X occurred 700 times. That is all I can suggest for the information given.